# AWS Stepfunction access original input without passing field step to step

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

So the beginning, I pass these input to the step function.

```
{
   "token": "val"
}
```

and I have multiple steps for the step function.

How can I access the token variable correctly in each step, without passing the "token" variable from step to step?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) via `$$.` and thereby access the original input via `$$.Execution.Input`:

```
"token.$": "$$.Execution.Input.token"
```